# How do I retrieve the Nth item in multiple sorted lists as if there was one overall sorted list?

Tags: java, list, algorithm, sorting, sharding

I am working on a sharding problem.

- Imagine I have 10 lists.
- Each list has a series of items that are independently sorted.
- I want to get the Nth item as if all the lists were sorted together in one large list.

Do I need to sort the lists overall to get an item at a particular index?

I solved a similar but not equivalent problem where there is:

- 10 lists
- Each list represents a range of items that are after the previous list.

here's the code to iterate through all the indexes of the lists:

```
/* code to iterate through all items in order
    * threads refers to one of the lists */

    int sizes[] = new int[threads.size()];
    for (int i = 0 ; i < threads.size(); i++) {
        sizes[i] = threads.get(i).data2.size();
    }
    int n = 0;
    int thread = 0;
    int size = threads.size();
    int offset = 0;
    long iterationStart = System.nanoTime();
    while (thread < size) {

        // System.out.println(String.format("%d %d", thread, offset + threads.get(thread).data.get(n)));
        int current = offset + threads.get(thread).data.get(n);
        n = n + 1;
        if (n == sizes[thread]) {
            offset += sizes[thread];
            thread++;
            n = 0;
        }
    }
    long iterationEnd = System.nanoTime();
    long iterationTime = iterationEnd - iterationStart;
```

Here's the code to lookup an item by index.

```
        int lookupKey = 329131;
        int current = lookupKey;
        int currentThread = 0;
        int total = 0;
        while (current >= 0 && currentThread <= size - 1) {
            int next = current - sizes[currentThread];

            if (next >= 0) {
                total += sizes[currentThread];
                current -= sizes[currentThread];
                currentThread++;

            } else {
                break;
            }

        }
        long lookupEnd = System.nanoTime();
        long lookupTime = lookupEnd - lookupStart;
        System.out.println(String.format("%d %d",
                currentThread,
                total + threads.get(currentThread).data.get(current)));
```

I'm hoping there's some property of sorted collections that I can use to retrieve the Nth item in an overall sorted lists.

What I have in effect is multiple partial orders.

I have some other code that does a N way merge between multiple sorted lists. Is the fastest option to run this in a loop up to lookupIndex?

```
        int size1 = threads.size();

        int[] positions = new int[size1];
        Arrays.fill(positions, 0);
        PriorityQueue<Tuple> pq = new PriorityQueue<>(new Comparator<Tuple>() {
            @Override
            public int compare(Tuple o1, Tuple o2) {
                return o1.value.compareTo(o2.value);
            }
        });
        long startOrderedIteration = System.nanoTime();

        for (ShardedTotalRandomOrder thread : threads) {
            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
//                System.out.println(thread.data2.get(i));
                pq.add(thread.data2.get(i));
            }
        }
        List<Integer> overall = new ArrayList<>();
        while (!pq.isEmpty()) {
            Tuple poll = pq.poll();
            ArrayList<Tuple> data2 = threads.get(poll.thread).data2;
            if (positions[poll.thread] < data2.size()) {
                Tuple nextValue = data2.get(positions[poll.thread]++);
                pq.offer(nextValue);
            }
            overall.add(poll.value);
            // System.out.println(String.format("%d %d", poll.thread, poll.value));
        }
        System.out.println(overall);
        long endOrderedIteration = System.nanoTime();
        long orderedIterationTime = endOrderedIteration - startOrderedIteration;
```

Comment: So do I understand this correct, that if you have list1 with a size of 10, list2 with a size of 5 and list3 with a size of 20 and you want to get the 25th item, you really would like to get the 10th item of list3?

Comment: Assuming that list1, list2 and list3 are all independently properly sorted lists, and list1 is 5,10,15,20,25,30,35,40,45,50..., list2 is 2,4,6,8,10, list3 is 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20. The sorted order of list1+list2+list3 is [1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 4, 5, 5, 6, 6, 7, 8, 8, 9, 10, 10, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 20, 25, 30, 35, 40, 45, 50]
So the 10th item is 7. I am trying to work out if I need to sort the combined lists.

Comment: Okay, in that case I really see no other choice than creating a large combined list and sorting and using that combined list.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to resort them. Since each list is already sorted you can merge them as follows.  This uses a single method to merge two lists based on their relative values.  Then it returns that list and feeds it back into the method to merge it with the next list.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.List;

public class Merging {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Integer> list1 = List.of(5,10,15,20,25,30,35,40,45,50);
        List<Integer> list2 = List.of(2,4,6,8,10);
        List<Integer> list3 = List.of(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20);
        
      
        int nth = 10;
        List<List<Integer>> lists = List.of(list1,list2,list3);
        List<Integer> merged = lists.get(0);
        for (int i = 1; i < lists.size(); i++) {
            merged = mergeLists(merged, lists.get(i));
        }
        System.out.println(merged.get(nth));
    }
```

prints

```
7
```

- This works with any type that implements the [Comparable](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/18/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Comparable.html) interface.
- It will loop until one list is exhausted or until both indices exceed the combined list size.
- Once either list is finished, the other can be appended via the sublist.

```
    public static <T extends Comparable<? super T>> List<T> mergeLists(List<T> list1, List<T> list2) {
        List<T> merged = new ArrayList<>();
        int i1 = 0;
        int i2 = 0;
        while (i1 + i2 < list1.size() + list2.size()) {
            if (i1 >= list1.size()) {
                merged.addAll(list2.subList(i2,list2.size()));
                break;
            }
            if (i2 >= list2.size()) {
                merged.addAll(list1.subList(i1,list1.size()));
                break;
            }
            if(list1.get(i1).compareTo(list2.get(i2)) <= 0) {
                 merged.add(list1.get(i1++));
            } else {
                merged.add(list2.get(i2++));
            }
        }
        return merged;
    }
}
```

Comment: Many thanks for your answer and approach. It occurred to me I can stop merging when N is reached.

Comment: If `N` is an index, how will you know that no more values will be inserted in front of the `Nth` value.  The very last element in the last list could affect the result depending on the nature of the values.  At least, that is what I think.

Comment: WJS, Thank you for your comment. The list1, list2 and list3 are each independently sorted. So i can stop taking items from them when I have retrieved N items from any of them overall so far. If they weren't sorted then you would have the problem you mentioned due to the later item coming before an item you already retrieved

Comment: Remember that I merge the lists two at a time. Otherwise I would have to compare all values of each list at the first location, then the second, and ensure I accomodate different size lists. Consider if `list1=3,10,20,30` and `list2= 4,12,19,50`. Say you want item `2`.  After the merge the combined `list=3,4,10,12,19,20,30,50`.  Item `2` contains `10`.  Now say `list3=1,1,2,100,200`.  After the merge the result is `1,1,2,3,4,10,12,19,20,30,50,100,200`.  Item `2` is now `2`.  Sorry to belabor this point but I want you to be clear on how my algorithm works so it won't mislead you.

Comment: Ahh I see, the algorithm I'm experimenting with is a priority queue one similar to the algorithm at the bottom of my question. This algorithm lets me stop merging when I get to N. With your algorithm, I could stop merging two lists at N but not 3 lists for the reason you say. Thank your for your clarification. You are indeed right that your algorithm means I have to sort the entire list1+list2 to finish before going to list3.

Comment: Not sort, but merge.  But you are correct.  Good luck with this.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a relatively efficient (linear with respect to the number of lists) algorithm that leverages some of the power of streams, but avoids a full list merge.

**EDIT**: To address shortcomings such as array length checking, array destruction, and readability I have improved this example. For better comparison, I have used the same integer test data as the other answer.

This virtual queue backed by the (presumably) immutable array will not mutate or otherwise

```
public class VirtualQueue<T> {
    private List<T> list;
    private int index=0;
    public VirtualQueue(List<T> list) { this.list = list; }
    public boolean hasMore() { return index < list.size(); }
    public T pop() { return list.get(index++); }
    public T peek() { return list.get(index);}
}
```

(I suspect that there is an easier way to do this with standard collections)

```
List<Integer> list1 = List.of(5,10,15,20,25,30,35,40,45,50);
List<Integer> list2 = List.of(2,4,6,8,10);
List<Integer> list3 = List.of(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20);

List<VirtualQueue<Integer>> listList = List.of(
    new VirtualQueue<>(list1),
    new VirtualQueue<>(list2),
    new VirtualQueue<>(list3));

int n=10;
var value = IntStream.range(0,n)
        .mapToObj(i -> listList.stream()
            .filter(VirtualQueue::hasMore)
            .min(Comparator.comparing(l -> l.peek()))
            .get().pop())
        .skip(n-1).findFirst().get();
//value is now the nth item in a hypothetical merged list.
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer and approach. I didn't even think of a streaming approach. I think I want to stop merging when N is reached which is what this answer does.

Comment: Unfortunately, `list.remove()` is an expensive operation.  Especially if you are removing the first element.  Using a linked list may help some.

Comment: @WJS, you are correct. I think the better way is to create a non-destructive queue on top of a (potentially) immutable list. In that case `.pop()` would merely advance some internal index of the Queue.

Comment: *some of the power of streams* - not very helpful for future Readers. I would rather say it creates `n` arrays of size `k` (assuming that there are `k` lists) under the hood and sorts them. It would have a cost of **O(n * k log k)** (because sorting of each array created by the stream would run in **O(k log k)**). So even without taking into account the cost of removal, the time complexity is *not* linear (as per youth attribution).  In fact, this solution has worse performance than others on this page and might fail depending on the input.

Comment: @AlexanderIvanchenko I believe I specifically commented on the lack of array exhaustion checking.  Your "proof" example was easily fixed by adding `.filter(l -> l.size() > 0)`  As for worse performance, I would be very interested in seeing your benchmarks that demonstrate this. (Also, I don't know what "as per youth attribution" means. Please be clearer.)

Comment: @EricGeorge I've explained what would be the time complexity of this solution, can you specify what exactly you found not unclear? If you disagree, then provide your analysis of the time complexity of the code you've written (there is no need to write a benchmark in order to evaluate big O). Your phrase about linear time complexity is definitely wrong.

Comment: @EricGeorge You really need to add the `filter` to the pipe-line, it's a must (*in order to handle an arbitrary input*), not something optional. With that fix, the issue with mutation of the original lists + not inability to deal with immutable lists remains.

Comment: Since the estimate of time complexity, provided by the author is misleading, it's **O(n * k log k)**, not linear, as I've explained above (since the problem is stated as *"retrieve the Nth item in **multiple sorted lists**"*, the number of lists is not specified it should not be treated as constant and neglected). Therefore, I'm voting down this answer.

Comment: Admittedly, the current solution with `min()` is way better than the one that used `sorted()` operation. It reduces the time complexity from **O(n * k log k)** to **O(n * k)** (where `k` is denotes the number of lists and `n` is the target element). But it still not ideal because it compares the same elements (every iteration of your nested stream brings only one new element, the rest were examined previously).

Comment: I should point out that my collections of each of the sublists are ordered already with relation to themselves. So list1, list2 list3 are each independently sorted. list1 is sorted. list2 is sorted list3 is sorted but they are not sorted list1+list2+list3 sorted.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you have `k` sorted Lists, and you need to obtain the `n` from the aggregated List (but the merged list itself don't needed), then this problem can be solved in **O(n * log k)** time, and by using **O(k)** additional space.

***Note:***

- *If the code below looks too much involved, here's the rationale behind that. This solution is more performant than straightforward comparison of elements from each list which can be observed in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74902730/17949945) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74902826/17949945) answers, which time complexity **O(n * k)** (opposed to *O(n * log k)*). A moderate additional complexity is a cost of the performance gain, and note that it's still maintainable.*
- *In case you would need to materialize the merged sorted list (solution below is not doing this), you can simply combine the lists together and make use of the built-in Timsort algorithm implementation via `List.sort()`. Timsort is [very good at spotting the sorted runs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timsort#Operation), therefore sorting a list that consists of sorted chunks would have a linear time complexity.*

To address the problem in **O(n * log k)** time, we can maintain a [`PriorityQueue`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/PriorityQueue.html) which would always have a size of `k` or less (*therefore enqueue/dequeue operation would have a cost of* **O(log k)**). At the beginning, the Queue should be initialized by adding the very first element from each List.

Then we need to perform `n` iteration (to find the target element). At each iteration step the Head element of the Queue should be removed, and the next element originated from the same list should be added to the Queue (i.e. if let's say the 7th element from the 3rd List appear to be the Head of the Queue, then after removing it, we need to enqueue the 8th element from the 3rd List).

In order to be able to track from which List each element is coming from and what was its index in the List, we can define a custom type:

```
public class ElementWrapper<V extends Comparable<V>> implements Comparable<ElementWrapper<V>> {
    private V value;
    private int listIndex;
    private int elementIndex;
    
    // all-args constructor, getters
    
    @Override
    public int compareTo(ElementWrapper<V> o) {
        return value.compareTo(o.getValue());
    }
}
```

And here's how this algorithm for finding the `n`-th element can be implemented. As I've said, the time complexity is **O(n * log k)**, since we need `n` iteration step with each step having a cost of **O(log k)**. Additional memory required only to maintain a Queue of `k` element.

```
public static <T extends Comparable<T>> T getNElement(List<List<T>> lists, int n) {
    Queue<ElementWrapper<T>> queue = initializeWithFirstElements(lists);
    
    T result = null;
    int count = 1;
    
    while (!queue.isEmpty()) {
        ElementWrapper<T> current = queue.remove();
        
        if (count == n) { // target index was reached
            result = current.getValue();
            break;
        }
        count++;
        
        if (hasNext(current, lists)) {
            addNext(current, lists, queue);
        }
    }
    return result;
}

public static <T extends Comparable<T>> Queue<ElementWrapper<T>>
            initializeWithFirstElements(List<List<T>> lists) {
    
    Queue<ElementWrapper<T>> queue = new PriorityQueue<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < lists.size(); i++) {
        if (lists.get(i).isEmpty()) continue;
        queue.add(new ElementWrapper<>(lists.get(i).get(0), i, 0));
    }
    return queue;
}

public static <T extends Comparable<T>> boolean
            hasNext(ElementWrapper<T> current, List<List<T>> lists) {
    
    return current.getElementIndex() + 1 < lists.get(current.getListIndex()).size();
}

public static <T extends Comparable<T>> void
            addNext(ElementWrapper<T> current, List<List<T>> lists,
                    Queue<ElementWrapper<T>> queue) {
    
    ElementWrapper<T> next = new ElementWrapper<>(
        lists.get(current.getListIndex()).get(current.getElementIndex() + 1),
        current.getListIndex(),
        current.getElementIndex() + 1
    );
    queue.add(next);
}
```

*Usage example:*

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<List<Integer>> input =
            List.of(List.of(1, 3), List.of(),
            List.of(2, 6, 7), List.of(10), List.of(4, 5, 8, 9)
        );
    
    System.out.println(getNElement(input, 1));
    System.out.println(getNElement(input, 3));
    System.out.println(getNElement(input, 9));
}
```

*Output:*

```
1    // 1st
3    // 3rd
9    // 9th
```

***Note:** depending how do you want the `n`-th element to be indexed the `count` variable in the `getNElement()` method should be initialized accordingly, i.e. with `1` if you want to use `1`-based indexes, and with `0` if you want `n` to be `0`-based.*

Comment: You have an off by one error.

Comment: @EricGeorge Elements in the example are `0`-based (element `1` corresponds to `n = 0`, and `10` - to `n = 9`). Do you really consider it to be an issue?? Start count from one if you wish, there's **no error** in the algorithm. Sorry, but your comment is contrived.

Comment: @EricGeorge I've updated the answer to address this "issue" (see the comment at the very end). Have you spotted anything else?